# Manual control of GKE generated forwarding rule

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I'm attempting to migrate from one infrastructure to another, both of which are in the same GCP project and region. I want the switch to be faster than I can rely on with DNS propagation, so was planning to change the `https-proxy-target` of the *forwarding-rule* that has the IP the A record is currently pointing at. This works, for a minute, but then the change gets reverted.

I'm fairly certain this is occurring because the forwarding rule and original `https-proxy-target` was generated by Kubernetes (the original infrastructure is on Google's GKE). Is there a way to take over control of a resource, or otherwise accomplish having the IP point to a new target in a way that is still easy to revert?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can get information for the related kubernetes object in GKE by looking for the `description` field in the `cloudshell` invoking commands given below or via Google Cloud Platform Console, reaching Load balancing page as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/target-proxies).

Describe `forwarding-rules`:

`$ gcloud compute forwarding-rules describe <BACKEND_SERVICE_NAME> --region <REGION>`

Describe `target-http-proxies`:

`$ gcloud compute target-http-proxies describe <TARGET_PROXY_NAME>`

Result might be something like this:

> description: '{"kubernetes.io/service-name":"..............."}'

Comment: The forwarding rules mostly have blank descriptions, though a few have the k8s info. Proxies don't even have a description field. Both have names in this format though: k8s-<type>-<namespace>-<name>--<id?>. Either way, my bigger question is can I regain control over that IP?

Comment: Maybe global static IP address will be useful here? Find more info in Google [document](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/configuring-domain-name-static-ip#step_2b_using_an_ingress).